# How can we validate JWT signature in Angular 6

Tags: azure-active-directory

Need help/steps to validate JWT token in Angular 6.o manually to validate or verify JWT Signature.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the Azure AD token, you may refer to the official tutorial: [Validating the signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-the-signature).

**First, you need to get the public key. In the header part of jwt token, you can get the kid.**

**Then you can get public keys from:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

or

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

**After that,  you can use the public key to verify the signature.**

Specifically, you can use [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) or [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose#jwt-verifying) in Node.JS to verify the signature.